# Powershell event handler context

Tags: powershell, events, event-handling

I try to subsribes to the SessionSwitch event with next command:

```
Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject ([Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents])
-EventName 'SessionSwitch' -Action { Write-Host "Session Changed" }
```

It works on Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2 and in Powershell ISE on Windows Server 2012 R2.
I lock and unlock session and in shell appears "Session Changed" message.
But it doesn't work if I run command in "common" Powershell shell on Windows Server 2012 R2.
Looks like I missed something important. Please, tell me what I have missed.

"Common" - powershell.exe, Powershell ISE - powershell_ise.exe

Comment: I can confirm, that this doesn't work in the PowerShell console on my Server 2012 R2 machine. No problems in ISE.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be the same issue as in: [Question about ISE vs Console with SystemEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55679774/question-about-ise-vs-console-with-systemevents)

Resolution is to run console as MTA instead of STA:

```
if ([System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.ApartmentState -ne [System.Threading.ApartmentState]::MTA)
{
    powershell.exe -MTA -File $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
    return
}
```

See the answer for a bit more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60641410/1819480